# Getting error while pushing data remotely into Azure Cosmos db via gremlin java client

Tags: java, azure, groovy, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I am trying to parse a CSV file and create nodes and edges into Cosmos db via the help of gremlin-java client ( https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-graph-java-getting-started ).

Some queries I have changed in this program:
For adding data :
Submitting this Gremlin 87246 query:

g.V().has('id','1120-L CONSOLIDATED SCHEDULE L').fold().coalesce(unfold(), addV('sub_schedule').property('id', '1120-L CONSOLIDATED SCHEDULE L').property('name', '1120-L CONSOLIDATED SCHEDULE L'))

For Creating edge:

g.V().hasLabel('parent').has('id', '1120').addE('has').to(g.V().hasLabel('state').has('id', 'FD'))

**After running it almost for 6 hours successfully it gives weird error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
at GetStarted.WriteWithOriginalCSVData.main(WriteWithOriginalCSVData.java:158)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:221)
at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:899)
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:275)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:652)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:575)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:489)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:451)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can somebody please tell me the possible causes for this?

To mention I am invoking this java client remotely from my laptop via open connection and hitting azure services ( in different location ).

Firstly I thought it might be because of my internet connectivity . But it exactly throws error when it has completed some 87-88k gremlin queries.
Can someone please let me know where I am going wrong here?

Comment: Do you know what query it is running when it closes?  Feels like the query is failing and causing the server to shut the connection on you...  Can you add some debug to cut down the dataset?

Comment: there's no particular query it fails. I have run that 4 times , and when I recorded this was the last query that went to server : g.V().has('id','1120-L CONSOLIDATED SCHEDULE L').fold().coalesce(unfold(), addV('sub_schedule').property('id', '1120-L CONSOLIDATED SCHEDULE L').property('name', '1120-L CONSOLIDATED SCHEDULE L')) .  But it ran successfully on first attempt. So again no particular query . This time it only ran upto 30K queries.

Comment: It got resolved by batching the data per connection . Thanks. But retry logic is another thing to build if one is testing remotely.